# @media query works fine in Chrome, but not working on mobile

Tags: html, reactjs, media-queries

I made an app by React. Everything is fine on laptop Chrome. But When I checked on my phone, @media query is not working. I read almost all questions and answers on stackoverflow. I could not find solution.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
```

and exapmle of my code

```
.home-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width:1366px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 400px){
  .home-wrapper {
    width:375px;
}
```

Could you help me? Thanks.

Comment: It is most likely your phone is wider than `400px`

Comment: How big is your phone screen? Most phones are bigger than 400px. Why not use a relative unit for width without the need for media-queries? `max-width: 1366px; width: 90vw`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is most likely your phone is wider than `400px` therefore doesn't enter the media query condition.

You can achieve what you want without using media queries, just using `max-width` with `width` like this:

```css
.home-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  max-width:1366px;
  width: 100%; /*or another value you want here like 90% or 90vw */
 /* just for demo */
  height: 200px; 
  background: lightblue
}
```

```html
<div class="home-wrapper"></div>
```